# How to debug code that interacts with low level APIs (like I/O completion ports)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, asynchronous, iocp

I wrote a console application that uses  `Socket`'s `*Async` set of methods and it crashes time to time. It doesn't show me where it threw the exception like synchronized code, console just shuts down and I have no idea what have I done wrong.

Is there a way to detect exceptions when it comes to asynchronous operations like this without knowing where to put a `try`/`catch` block?

All I need is to know what part of the code makes my application crash.

**Edit:**

The usual thing with the unhandled exceptions is when you are debugging your code using Visual Studio, it pauses the execution and shows you the line of code that caused the exception (or at least the exception message). But in some situations (e.g. interacting with a low level API like IOCP) your program just crashes and debugging ends with no information about its cause.

What I need is a way to see that particular exception:
"What happened or where (in which method) it happened so my program crashed?"

So I don't ask "What have I done wrong?", I ask "How can I find out what have I done wrong?"

- Can I make the execution break at the point where the exception is thrown?
- Can I see the call stack after crash to identify the method that caused it?
- Could you provide any advice to avoid these kind of situations?

Comment: Could you post some of your code so we can see how you are structuring things?

Comment: @wdavo: It is like 500 lines of code, calling Socket's AcceptAsync, ReceiveAsync, SendAsync, and I don't hanve _any_ idea where it goes boom. Besides, I'd like to know a generic solution for asynchronous applications. It happened to me before on early projects and I know that it will happen again in a different context, so I need to know "how to debug asynchronous code" (if it's possible) more than I need to fix the broken part of the code in my current project.

Comment: Until we see your code it's hard to know what you're not doing right...

Comment: But @Len, it's not "what I'm not doing right" that I'm asking. Please see my edit about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Debug-menu -> Exceptions`. Make sure `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` are thrown. Sometimes the IDE unchecks this option. I don't know why, but it's annoying.

Comment: User-Handled is checked for all items under the CLR exceptions. Should I check Thrown?

Comment: @ŞafakGür Yes, thrown should be checked.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that and get back to you as asap.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [System.Net logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203855.aspx) to see whats happening underneath